# Modifying iframe Content using selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to modify the content of a iframe with new content using selenium webdriver.

**Note:** 
I have already tried this below given approach:

```
driver.swithTo().frame(frame_webelement);
driver.findElement(By.xxx).sendKeys("Mycontent");
```

And I am able to clear the contents of body which is inside the iframe(using MyWebElement.clear()).

But I am not able to send the new content using MywebElement.sendKeys().

So I tried using below given javascript:

```
if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('iframeClass')[0].contentDocument.body.innerHTML='hello_text'");
    }
```

i am getting an exception as "document.getElementsByClassName('iframeClass')[0]" is undefined. but however the same script works fine with fireBug.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Switch to the iframe
driver.swithTo().frame(frame_webelement);

// then execute the JS
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.body.innerHTML='hello_text'");
```

Your `switchTo()` worked, and your `JavascriptExecutor` worked. Now you just need to combine both approaches. You don't need to select the iframe in JS, because you are already inside after `switchTo()`